# Qt project with custom shared library cross compile Qt

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I built Qt 5.9.4 for cross-compile on Raspberry Pi 3. Everything works fine with test applications. My problem is following:

Created static library in Qt Creator which is named `SlaveDeviceModels`. I deployed this library to raspberry and run this command on rpi:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/pi/Documents/QtProjectsTests/SmartHomeServer
```

Then I created console application project which is named `SmartHomeServer` and added to this project external library `SlaveDeviceModels`. Then I tried to run this application through Qt Creator but I get error:

```
/home/pi/Documents/QtProjectsTests/SmartHomeServer/SmartHomeServer: error while loading shared libraries: libSlaveDeviceModels.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Application finished with exit code 127.
```

So I go to rpi folder and it looks following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/QtProjectsTests/SmartHomeServer $ ls -l
total 3048
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 2122400 Mar 17 14:10 SmartHomeServer
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    9006 Mar 17 14:04 SmartHomeServer.log
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi      29 Mar 17 13:28 libSlaveDeviceModels.so -> libSlaveDeviceModels.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi      29 Mar 17 13:28 libSlaveDeviceModels.so.1 -> libSlaveDeviceModels.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi      29 Mar 17 13:28 libSlaveDeviceModels.so.1.0 -> libSlaveDeviceModels.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi  980428 Mar 17 13:28 libSlaveDeviceModels.so.1.0.0
```

Then I tried to run this app by `./SmartHomeServer` and it worked fine. It started.

Only problem is when I'm trying to start `SmartHomeServer` from Qt Creator on my local computer (cross-compile). Does anyone can help me where might be problem. Maybe missing settings in Qt Creator?

This is my `SmartHomeServer.pro` file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = SmartHomeServer
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# Default rules for deployment.
target.path = /home/pi/Documents/QtProjectsTests/SmartHomeServer
INSTALLS += target

# here are included my headers
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../SlaveDeviceModels

# I tried do something like that
#LIBS += -L/home/pi/Documents/QtProjectsTests/SmartHomeServe -lSlaveDeviceModels

# that are default lines added by qt creator
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build-SlaveDeviceModels-Raspberry_Pi_3_Kit-Debug/ -lSlaveDeviceModels
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../build-SlaveDeviceModels-Raspberry_Pi_3_Kit-Debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../build-SlaveDeviceModels-Raspberry_Pi_3_Kit-Debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to resolve is by adding these lines of code to you .pro file:

```
unix:!mac {
    LIBS += -Wl,-rpath=\\\$$ORIGIN/libs
}
```

so now you can put all the required libraries in the libs subfolder of your executable.

This approach is not required on Windows or Mac.
Please remember to use the qt.conf file for the Qt plugins.
Regards.